# javafx how to reuse custom component in different FXML

Tags: javafx-8

After several searching i could find any solution for this and would like to ask for help. Thanks in advance.

I have a FXML with HBox with several buttons (new, show, edit). Each button has onAction method. It is used in other 2 FXML (A & B) and I would like to reuse such HBox.

Other 2 FXML (A, B) have some controls (tableview, ...)

This is what i tried:

1) import HBox FXML is not an option as changes must be performed in all FXML (a & b).

2) include using fx:id: I will have a dedicated controller for HBox and I would like to have controls and methods on A, B controllers.

3) include using fx:root: I think this is the way to achieve this but i have errors.

Navigation.fxml file:

```
<fx:root spacing="5.0" type="HBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="btnOpen" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onActionOpen" text="Open" />
        <Button fx:id="btnSave" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onActionSave" text="Save" />
        <Separator visible="false" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
        <Button fx:id="btnClose" layoutX="62.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onActionClose" text="Close" />
    </children>
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
    </padding>
</fx:root>
```

Pane1controller.java:

```
public Pane1Controller() {
        System.out.println("Pane1_Controller");
        NavigationController nav = new NavigationController();
        System.out.println("NavigationController ... done");

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("pane1.fxml"));
        System.out.println("setting root");        
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        System.out.println("setting controller");
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            System.out.println("loading fxml");
            pnlMain = fxmlLoader.load();
            System.out.println("done");
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("exception");
            pnlMain = null;
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
        System.out.println("done");

    } ...
}
```

- using setRoot ....

  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root
  value already specified.
  file:/C:/Users/ecejdap/data/DEV/dev.java.nb/Testfx_fxroot/dist/run573616745/Testfx_fxroot.jar!/testfx_fxroot/pane1.fxml
- removing setroot
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root value already specified.
  file:/C:/Users/ecejdap/data/DEV/dev.java.nb/Testfx_fxroot/dist/run2127482879/Testfx_fxroot.jar!/testfx_fxroot/Navigation.fxml

Which is the correct way to achieve this?

Thanks for your support.
BR

Answer (score 0):

This must be caused due to the `<fx:root>` tag
I've created a sample project for the above task. Visit [GitHub](https://github.com/jayaneetha/FXReuse) for the project. Clone it and refer. I think you can understand it. [Link](https://github.com/jayaneetha/FXReuse)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm going to test ...

When I open the sample.fxml I cannot see the reusable component (child.fxml) and I want to see the final sample with all of the components (local and reusables)

Comment: Just see the Controller.java. I've added the child.fxml pane to the HBox of sample.fxml through Controller.java